# If rankT = rank $T^2$，How could I prove $\ker(T) \cap \text{Im}(T) = \{0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. Assume that
$$
\operatorname{rank} T=\operatorname{rank} T^{2}
$$
Show that $\operatorname{Ker} T \cap \operatorname{Im} T=\{0\}$.

Actually, I have an idea.
I remember a corollary: if dim V = dim W <=> V and W is isomorphism.Therefore ,T is an isomorphism. And $T(v) = 0$ if and only if $v = 0$, so $\ker(T) = \{0\}$.
And ImT is a subspace of V, so ImT have an zero vector .Then we got $\ker(T) \cap ImT = \{0\}$
But if I prove in this way ,$rank T = rank T^2$ is useless.

And another thing is ,I learn that course linear algebra [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TfctQeniugY&list=PLVJXJebpO4PgqQvz7FzQnLgBGRfPA5m8v&index=1).
And I do homework, but I can not find the solution, Does anyone else who find the solution of homework?

Comment: Please use mathjax formatting, I edited your post in parts to show you how you can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces with $\dim V = \dim W$, then there exists an isomorphism $f : V \to W$. Now, using this, how can you exactly conclude that $T$ is an isomorphism? You can't.

Instead, observe that from the rank-nullity theorem, $\operatorname{rank} T = \operatorname{rank} T^2$ implies that $\dim(\ker T) = \dim(\ker T^2)$, and since $\ker T \subseteq \ker T^2$, it follows that $\ker T = \ker T^2$. Now, for $v \in \ker T \cap \operatorname{im} T$, choose $w \in V$ such that $v = T(w)$ and then observe that $w \in \ker T^2$. Hence, $v=0$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I want to confirm something.  If dim V = dim W <=> V and W is isomorphism. This lemma means that there exists an isomorphism between V and W, right? I thought this lemma means that any linear transformation between V and W is isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, "$V$ and $W$ are isomorphic" means that there is an isomorphism between them.

Comment: Thank u very much!

Comment: I have a question, the conclusion v＝0,how can u get this, can u supply the details? Thanks

Comment: Yes :). 

If $v \in \operatorname{im} T$ then we can choose $w \in V$ such that $v = T(w)$. Now, if $v \in \ker T$ also, then $T^2(w) = T(v) = 0$, which means that $w \in \ker T^2 = \ker T$ and then $T(w) = 0$, that is, $v = 0$. Hence, $v \in \ker T \cap \operatorname{im} T$ implies that $v = 0$.

Comment: I understand,thank u very much.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you nearly got it right. The condition $\mathrm{rank}\;T = \mathrm{rank}\;T^2$ implies that if you restrict $T$ onto the subspace $\mathrm{Im}\;T$ , which of course is invariant, you will get an isomorphism.

Thus, any vector in $\mathrm{Im}\;T$ except $\mathbf{0}$ is non-zero under $T$. This is equivalent to say that $\mathrm{Im}\;T\;\cap\;\mathrm{Ker}\;T=\{\mathbf{0}\}$

Comment: Thanks your answer.